# Stored Procedure for Login Authentication not working MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am working Login Authentication with `Stored Procedures` in `MySQL` Database.
Below is the code, i wrote but its not working. Let me know, what is wrong.

### I have below questions

1. How to check, whether `CURSOR` is `empty` or `null`
2. Is there any way, we write the procedure.

### What I am doing..

1. Taking two `input` parameters and two parameters for `ouput`.
2. Check if the user or password is not valid, stored those values in OUT parameters 
   `SELECT 'Invalid username and password', 'null' INTO oMessage, oUserID;`
3. If user and password in valid, but `isActive` column is `0`  then 
   `SELECT 'Inactive account', 'null' INTO oMessage, oUserID;`
4. If success,
   `SELECT 'Success', v_UserID INTO oMessage, oUserID;`

### SQL Code

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `acl`$$


CREATE
    DEFINER = `FreeUser`@`localhost` 
    PROCEDURE `acl`.`checkAuthenticationTwo`(
    IN iUsername VARCHAR(50),
    IN iPassword VARCHAR(50),
    OUT oMessage VARCHAR(50),
    OUT oUserID INT
    )

    BEGIN
    DECLARE v_isActive INT;
    DECLARE v_UserID INT;
    DECLARE v_count INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT UserID, IsActive FROM m_users WHERE (LoginName = TRIM(iUsername) OR Email = TRIM(iUsername)) AND `Password` = iPassword;

    OPEN cur1;
    SET v_count = (SELECT FOUND_ROWS());

    IF (v_count > 0)

        FETCH cur1 INTO v_UserID, v_isActive;

        IF (v_isActive = 0) THEN
            SELECT 'Inactive account', 'null' INTO oMessage, oUserID;
        ELSE
            SELECT 'Success', v_UserID INTO oMessage, oUserID;
        END IF;

    ELSE
        SELECT 'Invalid username and password', 'null' INTO oMessage, oUserID;
    END IF;


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't need `CURSOR`s for that; use plain simple `SELECT`. A more concise version of your SP might look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = `FreeUser`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `acl`.`checkAuthenticationTwo`
(
    IN iUsername VARCHAR(50),
    IN iPassword VARCHAR(50),
    OUT oMessage VARCHAR(50),
    OUT oUserID INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 'Inactive account' ELSE 'Success' END,
           CASE WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN NULL ELSE UserID END 
      INTO oMessage, oUserID
      FROM m_users 
     WHERE (LoginName = TRIM(iUsername) 
           OR Email = TRIM(iUsername)) 
       AND `Password` = iPassword
     LIMIT 1; -- you better protect yourself from duplicates
    SET oMessage = IFNULL(oMessage, 'Invalid username and password');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*What it does it tries to select a row where username or email equals to iUsername and password equals to iPassword and outputs two values to output variables. Along the way it uses `CASE` to look at isActive value. If it's `0` then sets a message to 'Inactive' and NULL for userid. Otherwise it returns 'Success' message and real userid that has been found. Now, if a user has not been found both variables will be set to NULL. We can leverage that and use `IFNULL()` function to detect that fact and set a message to 'Invalid username and password'.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80641c/1)** demo
Personally I'd go further and simplify it a bit more and make it a one-statement SP with the following interface:

```
Returns: 
   userid (which is > 0) if a user with username and password if found
   0                     - username and(or) password incorrect
  -1                     - a user is inactive
```

The idea is that it's a presentation layer's task to produce appropriate messages for the user  and not scatter all those message literals across data layer.

```
CREATE DEFINER = `FreeUser`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `acl`.`checkAuthenticationThree`
(
  IN iUsername VARCHAR(50),
  IN iPassword VARCHAR(50),
  OUT oUserID INT
)
  SET oUserID = IFNULL(
  (
    SELECT CASE WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN -1 ELSE UserID END
      FROM m_users 
     WHERE (LoginName = TRIM(iUsername) 
           OR Email = TRIM(iUsername)) 
       AND `Password` = iPassword
     LIMIT 1 -- you better protect yourself from duplicates
  ), 0);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/189ad/3)** demo